# Почему не работает такой код?

Tags: php

Почему не работает такой код?

```
public function get($id) {
   return array_filter($this->users, function ($user) {
       if (strcmp($id, $user->getId())) {
          return $user;
       }
       return null;
   });
}
```

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: ну он мне постоянно массив дает, а должен вернуть null или же исключительно только тот массива который указал в параметрах

Comment: вот как этот код под пхп сделать? return productList.stream().filter(product -> product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(productName))
                .findAny().orElse(null);

Answer (score 0):

Надо передать $id в анонимную функцию

```
public function get($id) {
   return array_filter($this->users, function ($user) use ($id) {
       if (strcmp($id, $user->getId())) {
          return $user;
       }
       return null;
   });
}
```